# Is there a way to save the length of a list in a variable while doing recursion?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

let's say I have a recursive function that takes two lists and returns an int like so

```
fn ys (x:xs) 
       | --some condition = original length of (x:xs) 
       | otherwise = fn ys xs
```

I need to return the original length of the my input list (before recursion has messed with it) if condition one is true.
Is there a way to save the original length?

Comment: Do you want the current length or the total length?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what's the "some condition?"

Comment: @thefourtheye i want the total length

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the recursion with a "worker" function (traditionally named `go`), which allows you to refer to the original parameters and also to define extra variables:

```
fn ys xs' = go xs'
  where
    l = length xs'
    go (x:xs) 
           | --some condition = l
           | otherwise = go xs
```

You probably want a case for `go []` as well.

Comment: yea i want fn ys xs (original length)

Comment: @thefourtheye Since the OP code doesn't make much sense just to calculate the length of a list, I assume it's a simplification of what's actually needed, so I'm trying to show the general method.

Comment: @thefourtheye I assumed the condition might refer to the recursive `(x:xs)`, so I cannot just leave it out. And passing the length of `xs'` into `go` isn't necessary when it is already in scope.

Comment: I just realized while writing my answer I'd factored away the saving into a variable which the question title asked for. Adding it back in.